# Room query with id doesn't return the right list RxJava MVVM architecture

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, rx-java, android-room

I have a problem concerning my query returns, I have a student class that contains a string id from another table

```
data class StudentEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        val idStudent: String,
        val classId: String,
        val name: String,
        val notes: Note?,
)
```

I also created a room database that I'm populating from my api call

```
@Database(entities = [Student::class, Note::class], version = 14, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun programDAO(): ProgramDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) : AppDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "student-database"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and for that, I have a programDao that helps me to run my queries

```
@Dao
interface ProgramDAO {

    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from studentEntity")
    fun getStudents(): Single<List<StudentEntity>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from studentEntity where classId = :classid")
    fun getStudentsWithId(classid: String): Single<List<StudentEntity>>

}
```

In order to execute those queries, I have my Repository:

```
class ProgramRepository(val api: ApiService, val programDAO: ProgramDAO) {

    fun getStudentsFromDbWithId(idClass: String) : Observable<StudentEntity>{
        return programDAO.getStudentsWithId(idClass).toObservable()
    }

    fun getStudentsFromDb() : Observable<StudentEntity>{
        return programDAO.getStudents().toObservable()
    }
}
```

The MV allows me to connect the data and the view:

```
class ProgramListViewModel(private val programRepository: ProgramRepository) {
  fun getListFromDBWithId(classID: String): Observable<List<StudentEntity>> {
        return programRepository.getStudentsFromDbWithId(deliverySiteId)
    }


   fun getListFromDB(): Observable<List<StudentEntity>> {
        return programRepository.getStudentsFromDb()
    }

}
```

So in order to use the data and get the adapter and the KPIs on my fragment, I don't receive the right list from the database, I did log the results to see what I get, to start, I do log the whole list without id, and I have the list, but when I use an ID like:

```
subscribe(programListViewModel.getListFromDBWithId("111").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                Log.e("list of students", it.toString())
            })
```

I got an empty list, so I thought the problem was from the id, I tried to use the id that has been logged from the whole list and didn't work, I also used S to launch my sql query with the same id and I got the results.
Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `AircraftEntity` supposed to be `StudentEntity`? If yes (and I think it is, according to the rest of your code examples), then please update your question.

By default, Room uses the class name as the database table name, and I think it's case-sensitive, so your queries should have been `"select * from StudentEntity"`. The better approach would be giving it a name explicitly:

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
data class StudentEntity (
    // ...
)
```

Then, your `ProgramDAO` would look like follow:

```
@Dao
interface ProgramDAO {

    @Query("select * from students")
    fun getStudents(): Single<List<StudentEntity>>

    @Query("select * from students where classId = :classid")
    fun getStudentsWithId(classid: String): Single<List<StudentEntity>>

}
```

> You said: ... a room database that I'm populating from my api call

Where and how do you populate your database? I don't see any `@Insert` functions in your DAO, unless you just left them out from your code snippet. If your room DB is not populated, of course you will get no data.